# nmap detect service name with default port, what about using different port?

Tags: networking, nmap

I am using `nmap` to scan a `Linux machine`. It could show me `port: 3306, service name: mysql`. But if I install `tomcat` in `Linux machine` and made the listening port `1818` for tomcat, it could not show me the right `service name`, for example `apache-tomcat`, when I use `nmap` to scan the linux machine. The questions is whether it is possible to use `nmap` to scan the machine and return the right `service name` when service is not listening to the `default port`, `8080` for example?

Comment: The service name is based on the transport protocol and port number. Refer to the IANA _[Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)_ for the registerwd services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Nmap can detect the service on any port by sending application-layer probes and matching responses against a database of known services and applications. This feature is called [service and application version detection](https://nmap.org/book/vscan.html) and is activated with the `-sV` option. Note that some less-robust applications may crash or produce unusual errors when scanned in this way.

Comment: My case is that service is not on standard port, for example there are 8 tomcats running in same instance with different ports. In the link above it says 2200 services nmap could know. So I may not know what service the port runs. I have to use more network commands, like ps, ss, ...